# Tomcat 6 logger not receiving webapp log data

Tags: tomcat, logging, jenkins

I have multiple Jenkins instances running under localhost under separate contexts within an instance of Tomcat 6. I'm trying to configure filehandlers to read from the context logger associated with each application. According to the documentation:

```
A context is associated with the org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[enginename].[hostname].[path]
```

but when I attach a FileHandler as follows I get no output.

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[ABC].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[ABC].handlers = 6ABC.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
```

I am not an expert in Tomcat so I am not sure if it is possible to separate the logs of each webapp one on host into separate files. Is this a limitation of Tomcat, Jenkins or a configuration error on my part?

Answer (score 0):

You'll at least need to fix:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[ABC]
```

to

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/ABC]
```

(note the subtle '/' required to adequately identify the context)

Once that's done, you should definitely get log messages wherever a servlet does:

```
getServletContext().log("Hi!");
```

The Tomcat documentation [does promise](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html#Servlets_logging_API) this much.

However, it's [not clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19261727/in-tomcat-juli-do-the-facility-specific-loggers-become-per-webapp-logger-root) if the Loggers in the `[Catalina].[localhost].[/webapp]` hierarchy automatically become the root JUL logger for its respective webapp.